# Install ColdFusion 9 into MAMP Pro on OSX

Tags: mac-osx, coldfusion, mamp, osx-snow-leopard

I'm using [this video tutorial](http://blog.flashgen.com/2009/06/16/configuring-coldfusion-mamp-pro/) to try and install [ColdFusion 9](http://www.adobe.com/go/coldfusion) with [MAMP Pro](http://mamp.info/en/index.html) on my Macbook, for development purposes. It works when installing CF8; but with both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of CF9, I can't get it working.

I reach the 19 minute mark of the video and add index.cfm to the DirectoryIndex directive, then restart the services in MAMP Pro. Apache fails to stop, requiring a force-quit (not something I did manually, MAMP asked if I wanted it to try to force-quit, I said yes, and it seemed to do the job) and now when I try to start Apache I get the message:

> > Apache wasn't able to start. Please check log for more information.

This is what I see in the console log:

```
Syntax error on line 1131 of /Users/adam/Library/Application Support/living-e/MAMP PRO/httpd.conf:
Cannot load /Applications/ColdFusion9/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/mod_jrun20.so into server: cannot create object file image or add library
```

The mod_jrun20.so file mentioned in the error does exist at the indicated location.

The only other thing that has changed since this was working for me with CF8 was that I upgraded from Leopard to Snow Leopard. I did uninstall and re-install MAMP Pro after the Snow Leopard upgrade, though.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unzipping the wsconfig.jar file (found in {cf_root}/runtime/lib/wsconfig.jar). Therein you should find the stock 32-bit version of mod_jrun.so connector. Try using that one to replace the one that Apache is having trouble loading. That seems to have worked for other people who have had this problem

Comment: I ended up getting the correct file out of the 32 bit CF9 installer application (browsing into it in Finder); but this was the solution.

Comment: Here's a screencast I put together to show how to fix this: http://fusiongrokker.com/post/resolving-apache-coldfusion-connection-error-in-mamp-pro

Answer (score 1):

That happened to me as well when I installed CF9 on MAMP (not MAMP Pro) in multi-server mode (I already had CF8 installed and then I generated the EAR for CF9 and added it to JRun).
In my case, I'm pretty sure the reason was that I tried to install the 64 bit version of CF9. I read somewhere that Apache that comes in MAMP only runs in 32 bit mode and therefore can't load the 64-bit version of mod_jrun.so. When I uninstalled CF9 (and also made sure that mod_jrun.so was deleted) and re-installed the 32-bit version, all was well.
I'm not sure this will help you, though, since you stated that you're also having this problem with the 32-bit version. But I guess I would make sure that mod_jrun.so is deleted before re-installing. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that before... Sometimes, for whatever reason, the mod_jrun20.so file is corrupt. Try replacing it with the mod_jrun20.so file from another machine.